# Vue Resource Cross-site HTTP request

Tags: httprequest, vue-resource, vue.js

Normally, when I make a jQuery request to a non-local server, it applies [Cross-site HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) rules and initially sends an OPTIONS request to verify the existence of an endpoint and then it sends the request, i.e.

```
GET to domain.tld/api/get/user/data/user_id
```

jQuery works fine, however I would like to use Vue Resource to deal with requests. In my network log, I see only the actual request being made (no OPTIONS request initially), and no data is being received.

Anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Sample Code:

```
             var options = {
                 headers: {
                     'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx'
                 }
             };
             this.$http.get(config.api.base_url + 'open/cities',[options])
                 .then(function(response){
                     console.log('new request');
                     vm.cities = response;
                 }, function(error){
                     console.log('error in .js:');
                     console.log(error);
                });
```

[jquery-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gskyn.png)

Solution:

As @Anton mentioned, it's not necessary to have both requests (environment negligible). Not sure what I have changed to make it work, but the request gave me an error. It consisted in setting the headers correctly. Headers should not be passed as options but as a property of http:

```
this.$http({
   root: config.api.base_url + 'open/cities', // url, endpoint
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx'
   }
}).then(function(response){
                     console.log('new request');
                     vm.cities = response;
                 }, function(error){
                     console.log('error in .js:');
                     console.log(error);
                });
```

Thank you guys, it was a team effort :)

Comment: Could you show us a litlle the code you are using ans what options would you use ? Did you have a look at > https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/config.md ?

Comment: added some code... Looked up all config possibilities for vue-resource however the console shows only one request... explained in the question.

Comment: So if I understand, you want to "ping" the api url to know if it's available and then, perform the request ?

Comment: I don't know if you have ever noticed, but on the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools, a jQuery request (in this case named cities) it shows itself twice (even though I have coded only one request), once to check if it's valid as an endpoint, and the other one to get the returned object from backend. Now with Vue-Resource, it has only the first request. Allow me to add a couple of pictures on the question

Answer (score 1):

Is it a requirement that an additional `OPTIONS` request is being made? I have created a small (32 LOC) example which works fine and retrieves the data:

https://jsfiddle.net/ct372m7x/2/

As you can see, the data is being loaded from a non-local server. The example is located on *jsfiddle.net* and the request is made to *httpbin.org* - this leads to CORS being applied (you can see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the screenshot below).

What you also see is that only the `GET` request has been executed, no `OPTIONS` before that.

[image]

Comment: Of course not, it's not necessary, however I get no results that's why I had this assumption. I am not sure exactly what I have changed, but the result is different now. And it is working :) thanks for collaboration